# Discrete Math; BigO Notation: lease help me understand how this answer was arrived at.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Given

f(n) = $(2^n+n^2)(n^3+3^n)$

the answer is

O$|6^n|$

Can someone please explain to me how this happened?
Thank you!

Comment: Only the "fastest growing" term is relevant enough to keep track of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expand the product using the distributive law to get $$2^nn^3+6^n+n^5+3^nn^2$$and use the fact that exponentials dominate over polynomials.